# How to arrange values for line and point chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, ggplotly

With the help of this code i can get the total of each line chart but i dont know how to group the values for respective year range and also how to arrange the line to start from zero if there is no data

can anyone let me know how to acheive this...Thanks in advance
[image: expected outout][image: current output]

```
x = structure(list(Sector = c("Agri", "Agri", "Agri", 
    "Agri", "Agri", "Education", 
    "Education ", "Education", "Education", 
    "Education", "Energy ", "Energy ", 
    "Energy", "wealth", "wealth", "wealth", "wealth", 
    "wealth"), year_range = c("2017-2018", "2018-2019", "2019-2020", 
    "2020-2021", "2021-2022", "2017-2018", "2018-2019", "2019-2020", 
    "2020-2021", "2021-2022", "2019-2020", "2020-2021", "2021-2022", 
    "2017-2018", "2018-2019", "2019-2020", "2020-2021", "2021-2022"
    ), Month = structure(c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 5L), .Label = c("Apr", 
    "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", 
    "Feb", "Mar"), class = "factor"), total = c(1, 3, 9, 13, 13, 
    1, 6, 3, 1, 3, 1, 6, 9, 9, 12, 10, 4, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -18L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), sorted = c("Sector", 
    "year_range")


y =  structure(list(year_range = c("2019-2020", "2019-2020", "2019-2020", 
"2019-2020", "2020-2021", "2020-2021", "2020-2021", "2020-2021", 
"2020-2021", "2020-2021", "2020-2021", "2021-2022", "2021-2022", 
"2021-2022"), total = c(0, 9, 10, 22, 0, 2, 14, 27, 30, 22, 13, 
0, 39, 15)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), groups = structure(list(
    year_range = c("2019-2020", "2020-2021", "2021-2022"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:4, 5:11, 12:14), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Plan <- "#288D55"
x_labels = list(tickangle = -45,tickfont = list(family = "Arial",size = 10,color = "black",face="bold"))
y_labels = list(tickfont = list(family = "Arial",size = 10,color = "black",face="bold"))


    ggplotly(
  x %>%
    group_by(year_range) %>%
    mutate(total_year_range = sum(total)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = as.character(year_range), y = total, text = total_year_range))+
    geom_col(aes(fill = Sector))+theme_classic()+
    geom_line(data = y %>%
                mutate(total_year_range = sum(total)), aes(x=as.character(year_range), y= total, group=1,color="Plan"),size=0.8)+
    scale_colour_manual(name="",values=Plan)+
    geom_point(data = y %>%
                 mutate(total_year_range = sum(total)), aes(x=as.character(year_range), y=total),color="#288D55")+
    theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank(),legend.position = "bottom")+
    labs(x="", y="No.of total companies", fill="")+
    theme(axis.title.y =element_text(size=8))+
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#1F7A3F","#0AAA4D","#70B821","#9BDFAF"))+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE),expand = expansion(mult = c(0,.3))),tooltip = c("text"))%>% 
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.1, y = -0.2,font=list( family='Arial', size=10, color='black')),xaxis = x_labels,yaxis = y_labels)%>%
  config(displaylogo = FALSE,modeBarButtonsToRemove = list('sendDataToCloud', 'autoScale2d', 'resetScale2d', 'toggleSpikelines','hoverClosestCartesian', 'hoverCompareCartesian','zoom2d','pan2d','select2d','lasso2d','zoomIn2d','zoomOut2d'))
```

Comment: With the line chart, you want to group the values of the respective year range and then show the sum, right?

Comment: yes and also in point chart the point was showing in multiple places need to fix that one @Shibaprasadb

Comment: the ```y``` data frame didn't have those specific values for the year range that's why you weren't getting anything. I have added that and wrote a generalized code in the answer. Let me know if that was of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One note: There were two additional spaces for the `Sector` variable in your sample `x` which wasn't giving the right answer. So, I rechecked and removed them and then proceeded.

You're not getting any 0 for the first two bars because there isn't any 0 in the data frame for those years. So I have run a simple loop and created the two rows for the `y` data frame

```
i<-1
j<-1
year_range <- c()
while (i <= nrow(x)) {
  if(!(x$year_range[i] %in% y$year_range)){
    year_range[j] <- x$year_range[i]
    j <- j+1
  }
  i <- i+1
}

year_range <- unique(year_range)
total <- rep(0, length(year_range))

y_temp <- data.frame(cbind(year_range, total))
y_temp$total<-as.numeric(y_temp$total)
y <- rbind(y, y_temp)
```

Now, draw the plot, and you'll have what you desire. Here I have given an example on a simple ggplot, but you can customize it as you wish:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_col(data=x%>%
             group_by(year_range)%>%
             mutate(total_year_range = sum(total)) %>%
             ungroup(), aes(x=year_range, y=total, fill=Sector))+
  geom_line(data=y%>%
              group_by(year_range)%>%
              mutate(total_year_range = sum(total))%>%
              distinct(year_range, .keep_all = T), aes(x=year_range, y=total_year_range, group = 1))+
  geom_point(data=y%>%
               group_by(year_range)%>%
               mutate(total_year_range = sum(total))%>%
               distinct(year_range, .keep_all = T), aes(x=year_range, y=total_year_range))+
  xlab('Range of the year')+
  ylab('Total number of companies')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'top')
```

[image: Output]

Let me know if this solves your purpose.